# How do I restrict input in an Angular input box and keep the model correct?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am having a hard time implementing the equivalent of what used to be parsers and formatters from AngularJS.
My use case is not directly a parser/formatter, but here is what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a dynamic list of *keys*.
For each of those keys, the user can enter a value 0-100.
If the user inputs (keyboard or paste) any characters, they are stripped.
If the user inputs any number greater than 100, it is capped to 100.

For that, I created a *directive* that filters out what I need.
The directive works properly on the `input` element, but the underlying `form` is not getting the proper value as shown below.

[image: bad form]

The form seems to get my last input, no matter what.

**How can I prevent the update of the model for invalid values?**

I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzy5mc) for this. The gist of the code is:

*app.component.html*

```html
<form #form="ngForm">
  <div *ngFor="let key of list">
  <input name="{{key}}" ngModel appFilter >
  </div>
</form>

<pre>
form:
{{ form.value | json }}
</pre>
```

*app.component.ts*

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  readonly list = ['foo', 'bar'];
}
```

*filter.directive.ts*

```js
@Directive({
    selector: 'input[appFilter]',
})
export class FilterDirective {
    // TODO: remove directive?
    @Output()
    ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    value: string;

    @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
    onInputChange($event: TextInput) {
        const filtered = $event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
        if (filtered.match(/^[0-9]/)) {
            // starts with a number, must be a number
            const number = +filtered.replace(/\*/gi, '');
            $event.target.value = `${Math.min(100, number)}`;
        } else {
            // it must be empty string
            $event.target.value = '';
        }
        this.ngModelChange.emit($event.target.value);
    }
    constructor() {}
}

interface TextInput {
    target: {
        value: string;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `$event.target.value` you adapt the `input`'s value, but not the value of the underlying Angular `NgControl`. Luckily, `NgControl` can be injected into your directive whenever the `input` with the `appFilter` attribute also has an associated `ngModel`, `formControl` or `formControlName` attribute.

Inject `NgControl` into your `FilterDirective` and use it to set the value:

```js
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) { }

@HostListener('input', ['$event'])
onInputChange($event: TextInput) {
    const filtered = $event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
    if (filtered.match(/^[0-9]/)) {
        // starts with a number, must be a number
        const number = +filtered.replace(/\*/gi, '');
        this.ngControl.control.setValue(`${Math.min(100, number)}`);
    } else {
        // it must be empty string
        this.ngControl.control.setValue('');
    }
}
```

Should you expect cases where your `FilterDirective` is used without the `ngModel`, `formControl` or `formControlName` attribute; then make the injected NgControl `@Optional()`.

Comment: Thanks. This definitely did the trick. May I ask where you found this information (besides being super smart)? My original code was already borrowed from a few other answers on SO.

Comment: @EricLiprandi you may ask but I honestly don't remember. I've designed a lot of standard form components at my previous employer and probably had a somewhat similar use case at some point. I think I just read through the API documentation. I've used a similar approach with `ControlContainer` in my angular-reactive-validation library on Github. It can be found [here](https://github.com/davidwalschots/angular-reactive-validation/blob/master/angular-reactive-validation/src/validation-message/validation-message.component.ts).